# MS SQL Server 2008 R2 handling XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the following XML to handle in MS SQL Server 2008 R2.
I already went to a lot of answers but I could no solve my problem.

```
<ParameterValues>
   <ParameterValue>
      <Name>TO</Name>
      <Value>email1@gmail.com</Value>
   </ParameterValue>
   <ParameterValue>
      <Name>BCC</Name>
      <Value>email2@gmail.com</Value>
   </ParameterValue>
   <ParameterValue>
      <Name>IncludeReport</Name>
      <Value>True</Value>
   </ParameterValue>
   <ParameterValue>
      <Name>RenderFormat</Name>
      <Value>MHTML</Value>
   </ParameterValue>
   <ParameterValue>
      <Name>Subject</Name>
      <Value>SubjectOfMyMail</Value>
   </ParameterValue>
   <ParameterValue>
      <Name>IncludeLink</Name>
      <Value>False</Value>
   </ParameterValue>
   <ParameterValue>
      <Name>Priority</Name>
      <Value>NORMAL</Value>
   </ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

The result I need is the following:

[image: Desired result]

I think that there might be more than one TO and more than one BCC but never more than one subject.

If it will be useful i can post my code but it simply does not work.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Here! this works!

```
select  cat.ItemID,cat.Name  , sec.PolicyID
            ,Query.value('(./Value)[1]','nvarchar(1024)') AS Valore
            ,Query.value('(./Name)[1]','nvarchar(1024)') AS Tipo
      from MYserver.[ReportServer].dbo.Catalog as cat
            inner join  sec 
                  on  sec.ItemID=cat.ItemID
                  and sec.Name=cat.Name 
            CROSS APPLY sec.ExtentionSetting.nodes('//*:ParameterValue') Queries(Query)
```